# Why won't my images work?

Tags: html, image

I just started a new site on my new laptop and after writing in the content i checked it on Google Chrome. None of my images worked. The urls are all good but it's just not working. My code is below. I feel kinda dumb cause it's probably gonna be something really simple. Let me know what you think. Thanks!

```
<img src='images/logo.gif' alt='dylanbuth.us' />
```

I have a 64bit computer and 32bit chrome. Does that matter? I don't think so but might as well be thorough.

Comment: Can you in your relative path (your folder), there is an existence of the gif?

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: @AdrianCornish I'm just opening it from my computer. (right clicking the file and pressing open with Chrome)

Comment: @ajreal The picture is there. It is the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a problem with the location.

> `<img src='images/logo.gif' alt='dylanbuth.us' />`

You are telling a browser that in the same folder as the file, you have a subfolder called 'images'. In that folder you have a file called 'logo.gif'. Verify that this is correct.
If you can't find anything wrong, try stating the full location. This would look something like on windows

```
<img src='C:\\User\\Documents\\images\\logo.gif' alt='dylanbuth.us' />
```

Or maybe this on mac (or linux)

```
<img src='/user/home/Documents/images/logo.gif' alt='dylanbuth.us' />
```

Comment: fixed it. I was right in my original question. It was something simple. When I went to copy the absolute location from the properties of the file it said the name of it was '.../images/logo.gif.gif' guess when I changed the name to logo.gif I didn't need the extra .gif. Well thanks everyone for your help. Except for the guy that gave me -1. On to make my site. Feel free to check it out. dylanbuth.us . right now its just some php game I made. gonna make site soon. Thanks again

Comment: Good for you (although the game is a little buggy). I hope you continue with your site.

Answer (score 0):

So think of it like this - a web server creates a fake root of a drive and a lot of web developers use relative paths. So where ever the page is read from it is expecting a sub directory called images that contains logo.gif

The other alternative is to edit the HTML to point to exact locations on you disk for files ie

```
<img src="c:\\foo\\bar\\pic.png"/>
```